# How to convert mvc architecture to micro service architecture?

Tags: node.js, express, microservices

i have developed a shopping cart application using node.js and express framework. and there are 3 main modules in my app. user, cart, products are the those modules. it has been developed in MVC architecture. i would like to convert it to micro service architecture. how can i able to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways.

1. Split your express app into multiple express apps based on Modules you have.
2. You can keep only one express app and use the load balancer to route to your application.

eg : considering your user and cart module, if you have urls like

myapp/cart/*
myapp/user/*

then you have to deploy your application on respective instances and use the load balancer to route them accordingly.

you can explore more on load balancers [here](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)